# Does anyone recognize this condition on a Riemannian metric on a vector space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In the course of studying some oscillatory integral problems, the following strange condition came up.  Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space.  Let us say that a smooth Riemannian metric $g$ on $V$ is *good* if there exists a one-form $\omega \in \Gamma(T^* V)$ and a symmetric rank $(0,3)$ tensor $\Phi \in \Gamma(\mathrm{Sym}^3(T^* V))$ such that
$$ {\mathcal L}_Z g(X,Y) = \omega(Z) g(X,Y) + \Phi(X,Y,Z)$$
for all *translation-invariant* vector fields $X,Y,Z$, where ${\mathcal L}$ denotes the Lie derivative.  (Note that ${\mathcal L}_Z X = {\mathcal L}_Z Y = 0$, so I don't need to specify whether the left-hand side is ${\mathcal L}_Z(g(X,Y))$ or $({\mathcal L}_Z g)(X,Y)$, as they are equal.) Using a linear coordinate system $x^i$ for $V$, this condition can also be expressed in these coordinates as
$$ \partial_k g_{ij} = \omega_k g_{ij} + \Phi_{ijk}$$
where $\Phi$ is symmetric in the indices $i,j,k$.  One can eliminate the $\omega$ and $\Phi$ terms and write this condition as
$$ (\partial_k g_{ij} - \partial_j g_{ik}) g^{il} = 0$$
whenever $l \neq j,k$, with the usual raising and lowering conventions.

For instance, any constant-coefficient metric $g_{ij}(x) = g_{ij}$ is good; and any metric $e^{2u} g$ conformally equivalent to a good metric is also good.  If $V$ has dimension less than three, then all metrics are good (one can simply solve for $\omega, \Phi$ in terms of $g$ as this will be a determined linear system).  <strike>The direct sum of two good metrics is also good</strike>, and the pullback of a good metric by an invertible affine transformation is also good.

All of the above examples are "essentially two dimensional", and a naive dimension count seems to suggest that this should be roughly the correct expectation: good metrics should somehow be "generated" by examples from spaces of dimension at most $2$, though I do not know precisely what this "generation" should be.  This condition is however not familiar to me (it is not a purely differential geometry condition, as it does need the vector space structure on $V$, via the requirement that the vector fields $X,Y,Z$ be translation invariant).  Has anyone encountered any similar condition before?  Any references in particular would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could rephrase your condition more invariantly in terms of an affine flat torsion-free connection. There is some literature using non-torsion-free metric connections in Riemannian geometry (e.g. Thomas Friedrich and collaborators), but unfortunately I am not aware of literature using flat torsion-free connections in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eliminating just $\Phi_{ijk}$, the equation is $\partial_{[k} g_{j]i} = \omega_{[k} g_{j]i}$. This equation has the integrability condition
$$\begin{aligned}
  0 = \partial_{[l} \partial_{k} g_{j]i}
    &= (\partial_{[l} \omega_{k}) g_{j]i} + \omega_{[k} \partial_{l} g_{j]i} \\
    &= (\partial_{[l} \omega_{k}) g_{j]i} + \omega_{[k} \omega_{l} g_{j]i} \\
    &= (\partial_{[l} \omega_{k}) g_{j]i} ,
\end{aligned}$$
where we used the original equation to simplify the second term on the rhs. Raising the $i$ index and contracting with any 1-form $\lambda_i$, the integrability condition is just $d\omega \wedge \lambda = 0$. In 2 dimensions, this 3-form condition is of course trivial. In any higher dimension it implies that $d\omega = 0$, or that $\omega = du$ for some scalar $u$.

The conformal transformation $g_{ij} = e^{u} h_{ij}$ turns the equation into $\partial_{[k} h_{j]i} = 0$. I believe(*) that the only solutions are of the form $h_{ij} = \partial_i \partial_j v$ for an arbitrary scalar $v$ (obviously here its Hessian must be non-degenerate).

Thus, all "good metrics" in dimension higher than 2 must be of the form
$$
  g_{ij} = e^u \partial_i \partial_j v
$$
for some scalars $u$ and $v$. BTW, I don't really see how the "direct sum" property holds for good metrics, neither in this explicitly parametrized form, nor from the original equation.

(*) There may be a more classical reference, but at least the 3-dimensional version of this statement has been studied in

> *Pauly, Dirk; Zulehner, Walter*, [**The divDiv-complex and applications to biharmonic equations**](https://doi.org/10.1080/00036811.2018.1542685), Appl. Anal. 99, No. 9, 1579-1630 (2020). [ZBL1459.35126](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1459.35126).

More generally, one can start with the Hessian equation $\partial_i \partial_j v = 0$ and prolong it to a first order form where the operator looks like a flat connection. The image of this connection is (by the Poincaré lemma) equal to the kernel of the exterior derivative twisted by the connection. Undoing the prolongation, this shows that the image of the Hessian operator coincides with the kernel of $\partial_{[k} h_{j]i} = 0$. I can spell out the details if needed.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!  Yes, I made a mistake in the direct sum calculation.  The equation $\partial_{[k} h_{j]i}$ implies that $h_{\cdot i}$ is curl free, hence $h_{ji} = \partial_j \phi_i$ for some $\phi_i$; using symmetry we then get that $\phi$ i salso curl-free, so $\phi_i = \partial_i v$, giving the claim (*)

Comment: Yes, this is a simple enough case that (*) follows by elementary means. Inspired by the form of the solution, some searching reveals that at least one person has called such geometries [conformally Hessian](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geomphys.2023.104989).